# php-cgi.exe is getting hung intermittently

Tags: php, iis

I have been troubleshooting an issue with php-cgi.exe getting hung intermittently,not able go past certain point.Any help will would be appreciated.

IIS 8.5 +php 5.4.25

when the request comes to IIS,I see that it is getting queued.Fast cgi is trying to spawn a new php-cgi.exe process but i see following pattern of hang in the process monitor trace

```
8:34:23.0975600 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       RegOpenKey     HKU\.DEFAULT\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC                NAME NOT FOUND         Desired Access: Read     9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM    00:00:03.3090228              0.0000045                
8:34:23.0975645 PM        Registry                648         Read
8:34:23.0975789 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       RegQueryKey    HKLM    SUCCESS              Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0               9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM    00:00:03.3090417              0.0000019            
8:34:23.0975808 PM                Registry                649         Read
8:34:23.0975891 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       RegQueryKey    HKLM    SUCCESS              Query: Name     9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM          00:00:03.3090519              0.0000032                         

8:34:23.0975923 PM        Registry                650         Read
8:34:23.0976035 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       RegOpenKey                HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC          NAME NOT FOUND         Desired Access: Read                9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM    00:00:03.3090663              0.0000077            
8:34:23.0976112 PM        Registry                651                Read
8:34:23.0980451 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       CreateFile           C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll      SUCCESS                Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened         9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM                00:00:03.3095079              0.0000285            
8:34:23.0980736 PM        File System         652         
8:34:23.0981085 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       QueryBasicInformationFile          C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll                SUCCESS              CreationTime: 8/21/2013 9:16:44 PM, LastAccessTime: 8/21/2013 9:16:44 PM, LastWriteTime: 8/21/2013 9:16:36 PM, ChangeTime: 2/4/2014 7:58:00 PM, FileAttributes: A          9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM                00:00:03.3095713              0.0000038            
8:34:23.0981123 PM        File System         653         Read Metadata
8:34:23.0981261 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       CloseFile              C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll      SUCCESS                                9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM    00:00:03.3095889              0.0000090            
8:34:23.0981351 PM        File System                654         
8:34:23.0983027 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       CreateFile           C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll      SUCCESS                Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened      9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM                00:00:03.3097655              0.0000215            
8:34:23.0983242 PM        File System         655         
8:34:23.0983651 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       CreateFileMapping         C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll      FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS     SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection:       9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM                00:00:03.3098279              0.0000032            8:34:23.0983683 PM        File System         656         
8:34:23.0983949 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       CreateFileMapping         C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll                SUCCESS              SyncType: SyncTypeOther           9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM    00:00:03.3098577              0.0000016                
8:34:23.0983965 PM        File System         657         
8:34:23.0984397 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       CloseFile              C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll      SUCCESS                                9/20/2014 8:34:23 PM    00:00:03.3099025              0.0000070            
8:34:23.0984467 PM        File System                658         
8:34:23.0990797 PM        php-cgi.exe        8112       Thread Create                   SUCCESS              Thread ID: 7928 9/20/2014 
8:34:23 PM          00:00:03.3105425              0.0000000            8:34:23.0990797 PM        Process 659
```

looking at php-cgi.exe memory dumps,i see

```
013df45c 1000783f KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12 
013df58c 10005594 php_wincache!aplist_ocache_initialize+0xff [c:\php-    sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\pecl\wincache\wincache_aplist.c @ 1116]
013df624 72efa6ed php_wincache!zm_startup_wincache+0x3f4 [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\pecl\wincache\php_wincache.c @ 790]
013df640 72e7a2fb php5!zend_startup_module_ex+0x4d [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.25\zend\zend_api.c @ 1696]
013df654 72f0f050 php5!zend_hash_apply+0x1b [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.25\zend\zend_hash.c @ 716]
013df674 72f00617 php5!zend_startup_modules+0x20 [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.25\zend\zend_api.c @ 1823]
013df948 00bd2af2 php5!php_module_startup+0x647 [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.25\main\main.c @ 2223]
013df958 00bd1ac9 php_cgi!php_cgi_startup+0x12 [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.25\sapi\cgi\cgi_main.c @ 937]
013dfae4 00bd38d1 php_cgi!main+0x1a9 [c:\php-sdk\php54dev\vc9\x86\php-5.4.25\sapi\cgi\cgi_main.c @ 1911]
013dfb28 7702495d php_cgi!__tmainCRTStartup+0x10f
```

I am not sure what is causing the php-cgi.exe process to get hung right after loading odbc dll. I am seeing all the php-cgi.exe process getting hung with the same behavior.Killing all the php-cgi process will get back everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the wincache module. A fix is in the developer channel.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68107

From the bug:

Please pick up 1.3.6.2, which has a fix for this issue.

Additionally, 1.3.6.2 adds a new setting that can be used to disable Shared Reader/Writer (SRW) locks.  By default, WinCache uses SRW locks.  Disabling them will incur a slight performance hit, but is robust against byzantine failures where php-cgi.exe instances get killed while WinCache is holding a shared lock.  The new php.ini setting is:

wincache.srwlocks=0 ; default is 1.

1.3.6.2 is available out on SourceForge in the developer releases folder.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/files/development/